# R - create variables in a dataframe using other variables with a for loop

Tags: r

Sorry if this is too simple a question but for the life of me cant sort this out.

I have a data frame with a continuous variable and need to create multiple logical variables based on the value of the continuous variable.

Hopefully the example below illustrates this:

```
x <- as.integer(rnorm(n=1000, mean=10, sd=5))

y <- 1:1000

df <- data.frame(x,y)

for i in 1:10 {

  df$[i] <- ifelse (df$x<[i],1,0)

}
```

I suspect I am going wrong at the `df$[i]` expression...any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want (using your code)

```
for(i in 1:10){
  df[paste0("Col",i)] <- ifelse(df$x <i, 1, 0)
 }

 head(df,3)
 #   x y Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
 #1  7 1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 #2 12 2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 #3 12 3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Or

```
 df[paste0('Col',1:10)] <- Vectorize(function(x) df$x < x)(1:10)+0
```

Or

```
 df[paste0('Col', 1:10)] <-  (do.call(cbind,Map(`<`, list(df$x), 1:10)))+0
```

Or

```
df[paste0('Col', 1:10)] <- matrix((df$x < rep(1:10, each=nrow(df)))+0, ncol=10)
```

Or

```
df[paste0('Col', 1:10)] <- `dim<-` ((df$x < rep(1:10, each=nrow(df)))+0,
                                               c(nrow(df),10))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- as.integer(rnorm(n=1000, mean=10, sd=5))
y <- 1:1000
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Comment: worked like a charm akrun - cheers buddy!!! saved me oodles of time. One of the great reasons why i love the R community!

Answer (score 1):

You can add new columns to a data.frame easily by assigning to them. On the LHS specify the column dereference and on the RHS specify an expression that computes to a vector, which should have the same length as the other columns that already exist in the data.frame. For example, if you want to add a logical column that captures if the x value in the same row is less than the mean of the normal distribution you used to calculate all x values, you can do this:

```
df$z <- df$x<10;
```

You don't need a for loop to do this. Many operations in R are vectorized, meaning they automatically loop through all elements of vector operands. The `df$x<10` snippet in that line of code tests every one of the 1000 values in df$x to see if it's less than 10, and the whole operation returns a vector of 1000 logical values (each TRUE, FALSE, or NA) with the results of the vectorized operation. So you can assign that result directly to a new column in the data.frame.